# Which JVM parameter should i use to instruct JVM to start Garbage collection

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm

I have noticed that after I moved my application server from Oracle JDK to SAP JVM, the garbage collection happens at ~70%-80% of Heap size. Earlier while using Oracle JDK, it used to happen when heap size reaches ~50% without any additional configuration.

I am trying to understand how to instruct JVM to perform a GC at 50%. I have not yet tried the following options, but I need to understand what the effects will be if I use them:

```
MinHeapFreeRatio
MaxHeapFreeRatio
```

My current JVM properties:

```
/sapjvm1.8.0_181/jre/bin/java -server -Xmx20G -Xms20G -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetail
```

I would appreciate it if someone can help guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=50`

`MinHeapFreeRatio` and `MaxHeapFreeRatio` affect how agressively the heap grows and shrinks. Since you've set `Xmx`=`Xms`, you probably don't want the heap to resize.

Comment: Thanks @apangin. However i did not find the option -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=50 anywhere in SAP documentation. Just wondering if i can apply it to SAP JVM.

Comment: @Vishnu As far as I know, SAP JVM is a modified version of HotSpot. I believe that HotSpot options should work there, too. In the [presentation](https://youtu.be/IsERHnGn7Vs?t=1300) about SAP JVM Internals there is indeed `InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent` in the list of JVM options.

Comment: For almost all server processes, `Xmx` should be == to `Xms`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. We decided to stick to existing value since it was ok for us. wever you are right, the same option works for SAP jvm as well. thanks